# querying aggregate EAV records by month and multiple other fields

Tags: mysql, laravel, entity-attribute-value, materialized-views

I have entities set up in an Entity-Attribute-Value model.  This is in Laravel.  Now I need to run a report where these are grouped by the year and month of a user-defined custom field (that happens to be a date) and also by another field 'type'=(one of many different types).

The only solution I can think of for this is to create caching MySQL tables, that are sort of like materialized views but are updated through the model (because MySQL does not yet support materialized views), and then query those indexed tables.

Are there other ways I'm not thinking of that might serve me better?

Answer (score 0):

I would just query the data as-is, and process the rows into group using client code.

Actually, I would not use EAV for attributes that I need to use in searching, sorting, or grouping.

"Arbitrary custom fields" and "data model" are antonyms.

Comment: Thanks.  I meant 'user-defined' rather than 'arbitrary'.  Changed.  So what model would you use for user defined fields and entities that need to be searched and grouped?

Comment: There are a number of options, each with their own pros and cons. See my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling). But my point is that allowing user-defined attributes is inherently non-relational, and breaks the concept of a data model.